# Correct use of condition variables

Tags: c++11, condition-variable

I have the following timing code, and it seems to be not waiting on the condition variable as desired. The goal is to spawn all threads, and then have them all start work at the same time.

Premature seems to be called. Any ideas why?

```
chrono::milliseconds timeNThreadsLockFree(int n, int worksize)
{
    boost::lockfree::stack<int> data(totalNumberOfWorkItems);
    vector<thread> ts;
    atomic<int> count;
    condition_variable cv;
    mutex mut2;
    unique_lock<mutex> ul(mut2,defer_lock);
    lock(ul,mut);
    auto startSpawn = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ts.push_back(thread([&](){
        cv.wait(ul, [](){return true; });
        int q = 5;
        for (int j = 0; j < worksize; j++){
            data.push(7);
            else count++;}
    }));
    if (count != 0) {
        cout << "premature" << endl; }
    cv.notify_all();
    auto startWait = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (auto&& t : ts)
        t.join();
    auto endWait = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    if (count != totalNumberOfWorkItems)
        cout << "not done" << endl;
    return chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(endWait - startWait);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the second argument to the `cv.wait` call. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) says the second argument a predicate called when spurious wakeup occurs, and that:

> predicate which returns ​false if the waiting should be continued

So, to make sure that the locking actually works, you should probably make a variable like `ready` in the main function, and then use that inside the waiting:

```
bool ready = false;
...
cv.wait(ul, [](){ return ready; });
...
ready = true;
cv.notify_all();
```

---

Also, you might want to try making a separate `std::unique_lock` for each of the threads, instead of re-using the one from the main function:

```
ts.push_back(thread([&]() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul2(mut2);
    cv.wait(ul2, [](){ return ready; });
```

Then, you'll also need to unlock the old lock in the main function:

```
ready = true;
ul.ulock();
cv.notify_all();
```

---

Finally, since you want all of the threads to be running at the same time, you'll probably want to manually unlock the inner `std::unique_lock`s so that more than one can run:

```
ts.push_back(thread([&]() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul2(mut2);
    cv.wait(ul2, [](){ return ready; });
    ul2.unlock();
```

Comment: If I remove the lambda I get "Lock being held by different context" as an assert fail in visual studio. Same deal if I make the lambda return false. Ideas?

Comment: The other thing to note is that I never want the lock the need to be reacquired. Is that being done in this case?

Comment: @soandos What happens if you try making a separate `std::unique_lock` for inside of each of the threads, with the same mutex, and then try waiting on that?

Comment: @soandos Okay I added some more suggestions.

Comment: My issue is that I want the lock the be unlocked just once, and then have all the threads be free to run whenever they can. Adding a lock as overhead seems wasteful.

Comment: @soandos It looks like each of the calls to `cv.wait` need to have their own separate lock. When they finish, they ensure that they hold the lock, so if you have more than one call with the same lock, they'll all be unlocking and locking the same lock, which won't work. I added another suggestion which I think should make your program work as you want, even if it seems a bit wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

Having a bunch of lock/unlock/wait/notify all over the place is often a clue that you are using the wrong tools. Use `boost::barrier` (or roll your own, it's trivial to implement):

```
boost::barrier bar(n+1);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    ts.push_back(thread([&](){
        bar.wait();
        // ...
    }));
// ...
bar.wait(); // after this line all threads will be released from the barrier
```